# Fallback for TYPO3 FAL references fieldname

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

This should be a simple TypoScript question: 
I d like to define a fallback field for a FAL image. The default image should be received from a custom field added to the pages table called ogimage. If there`s no image in this field, the image should be received from the media field instead. This is how I tried to make it work - I commented out the different non-working approaches:

```
    page.meta.og:image {
    cObject = FILES
    cObject {
        references {
            table = pages
            uid.field = uid
            fieldName = media
            #fieldName.field = ogimage // media
            #fieldName.override = ogimage
            #fieldname.override.required = 1
            #fieldName.override.if.isTrue.field = ogimage
            #fieldName.override.if.isTrue.data = page:ogimage
        }
        renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
        renderObj {
            stdWrap.prepend = TEXT
            stdWrap.prepend {
                data = getIndpEnv: TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST
                wrap = |/
            }
            file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
            file.maxW = 1500
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, we had the same problem and your question inspired me. You've been quite close to the solution. This should work:

```
page.meta.og:image {
    cObject = FILES
    cObject {
        references {
            table = pages
            uid.field = uid
            fieldName = ogimage
            fieldName.override = media
            fieldName.override.if.isFalse.field = ogimage
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Since fieldName only contains the field's name there is no image reference or something like that. It is just a string but - as you have tried - the property is stdWrap-able. So the override provides an alternative field name. This is only applied your custom field is empty ("0" which means it has no reference to sys_file_references).

Comment: Thank you  - that was quiet a while ago. Looking at my question I really don`t know why I tried to do it the other way round, I really appreciate your feedback and will try your solution.

Comment: Thanks mate for your feedback. To be honest,I have tried it with TYPO3 v8 and not v7. Maybe it is different in v7. Let me if you get the expected result :)